# Why is answer sorting messed up?

Tags: support, answers, sorting

Answers are not ordered by 1) accepted 2) upvotes anymore. Why not? It is a pain to have to scroll through 0 upvote answers only to find one with 40 upvotes at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Did you change the sorting of answers? Need to change it back to "votes" instead of "active" or "oldest". https://i.stack.imgur.com/2178v.png